# Tufte-Book Class - Align three \enumerate environments side-by-side?

Tags: enumerate, tufte

I'm transcribing some of my lecture notes with the tufte-book template that's floating all over the internet. I want to have three enumerate environments side by side, but I'm not so sure how that can work. I know I have to use the

```
\begin{fullwidth}
\end{fullwidth}
```

commands to have text go across the full page, but it doesn't seem to work here.

```
\documentclass{tufte-handout}

%\geometry{showframe}% for debugging purposes -- displays the margins

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{textgreek}


% Set up the images/graphics package
\usepackage{graphicx}
\setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth,totalheight=\textheight,keepaspectratio}
\graphicspath{{graphics/}}

\title{Microbial Genetics Lecture}
\author[dfd]{did}
\date{2015}  % if the \date{} command is left out, the current date will be used

% The following package makes prettier tables.  We're all about the bling!
\usepackage{booktabs}

% The units package provides nice, non-stacked fractions and better spacing
% for units.
\usepackage{units}

% The fancyvrb package lets us customize the formatting of verbatim
% environments.  We use a slightly smaller font.
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\fvset{fontsize=\normalsize}

% Small sections of multiple columns
\usepackage{multicol}

% Provides paragraphs of dummy text
\usepackage{lipsum}

% These commands are used to pretty-print LaTeX commands
\newcommand{\doccmd}[1]{\texttt{\textbackslash#1}}% command name -- adds backslash automatically
\newcommand{\docopt}[1]{\ensuremath{\langle}\textrm{\textit{#1}}\ensuremath{\rangle}}% optional command argument
\newcommand{\docarg}[1]{\textrm{\textit{#1}}}% (required) command argument
\newenvironment{docspec}{\begin{quote}\noindent}{\end{quote}}% command specification environment
\newcommand{\docenv}[1]{\textsf{#1}}% environment name
\newcommand{\docpkg}[1]{\texttt{#1}}% package name
\newcommand{\doccls}[1]{\texttt{#1}}% document class name
\newcommand{\docclsopt}[1]{\texttt{#1}}% document class option name

\begin{document}

\section{Characterization of the 3 Domains}

    \begin{fullwidth}

    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
    \begin{fullwidth}
    \indent \textbf{Structural Features}
    \begin{itemize}
    \item{\# of chromosomes}
    \item{Nuclear Membrane}
    \item{Nucleolus}
    \item{Membrane Lipids}
    \item{Peptidogylcan}
    \end{itemize}
    \end{fullwidth}
    \end{minipage}


    \begin{minipage}[t]{1.0\textwidth}
    \begin{fullwidth}
    \textbf{Gene Structure/Transcription/Translation}
    \begin{itemize}
    \item{Introns?}
    \item{Transcription-Translation Coupled?}
    \item{Polygenic mRNA - polycistronic?}
    \item{polyA mRNA}
    \item{Ribosome (size/ SUs}
    \item{Amino acid carried by initiator tRNA}
    \end{itemize}
    \end{fullwidth}
    \end{minipage}




    \textbf{Other Processes}
    \begin{itemize}
    \item{Exo- or Endocytosis?}
    \item{Type of movement}
    \end{itemize}

    \end{fullwidth}

\end{document}
```

Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: Before piling up questions: consider to accept answers to your questions -- that's a way to thank users!

Comment: Hi Christian, I actually had no idea that there was that option to do so, thanks!

Comment: This is actually the 3rd time I have to remember you about this -- and it's not only my answers, of course others too.

Comment: Yup, I recall you told me to up vote, and I have, but I had no idea that I could accept an answer by clicking the check-box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

delete the `\fbox{...}` it is only for the demonstration:

```
\begin{fullwidth}
\fbox{\begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\textwidth}
\textbf{Structural Features}
        \begin{itemize}
                    \item{\# of chromosomes}
                    \item{Nuclear Membrane}
                    \item{Nucleolus}
                    \item{Membrane Lipids}
                    \item{Peptidogylcan}
                \end{itemize}
\end{minipage}}
\hfill      
\fbox{\begin{minipage}[t]{0.6\textwidth}
\textbf{Gene Structure/Transcription/Translation}
                \begin{itemize}
                    \item{Introns?}
                    \item{Transcription-Translation Coupled?}
                    \item{Polygenic mRNA - polycistronic?}
                    \item{polyA mRNA}
                    \item{Ribosome (size/ SUs}
                    \item{Amino acid carried by initiator tRNA}
                \end{itemize}
\end{minipage}}
\hfill      
\fbox{\begin{minipage}[t]{0.35\textwidth}
        \textbf{Other Processes}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item{Exo- or Endocytosis?}
            \item{Type of movement}
        \end{itemize}
\end{minipage}}     
\end{fullwidth}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Herbert. Do you mind explaining to me how you knew what to do? For example, what does \hfill do in this case? I ask because I want to be able to solve my own problems as well, and I've been reading guides, but I'm rather bad at doing so.

Comment: `\hfill` moves evrything to the right margin. With several `\hfill` the remaining space in the line is divided into the same space between the objects.